# Dynamic Linq to SQL query

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm upgrading my application from vb6 to .net and I'm trying to build a fully dynamic query in linq.

That is

```
Dim smth =  From res In (variable1) (variable2)
```

Where  variable1 would give me the tables (ex. table1 INNERJOIN table2,...) and variable 2 would give the operations needed on the end table.

I've tryied to do this

```
Dim dc As New DataClasses1DataContext
Dim smth= "dc.tblZDSepadores"
Me.dgRes.ItemsSource = From p In smth
```

And

```
Dim dc As New DataClasses1DataContext
Me.dgRes.ItemsSource = From p In dc.tblZDSepadores
```

But the results are not the same so I ask for your help

Comment: The second example reduces to `From p In "dc.tblZDSepadores"`. That doesn't even compile. We need running code to see what's going on. Also, *not the same* isn't too descriptive either.

Comment: that compiles. in the first example the datagrid (dgRes) is filled with data. In the second one, the rows appear but there is no data in them. The question is how to turn the query fully dependable on variables.